# How can I override a font awesome icon's pull right width for Internet Explorer?

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4, angular6, font-awesome

In our Angular6 project, I have a ngx-bootstrap4 accordion with a font awesome 5 icon with the pull right property, 
`<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', accordionOpen ? 'chevron-down' : 'chevron-right']" pull="right"></fa-icon>`

which looks like this in [Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gltrd.png). But of course, IE doesn't want to play nice, so it looks like this in [IE11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEr32.png).

I identified that removing `width: auto` does the trick from the CSS class `.svg-inline--fa .fa-pull-right` while in the dev tools for IE, however, if I try and target that class for IE using the media query

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
 .svg-inline--fa .fa-pull-right {
  width: 20px!important;
 }
}
```

in the component's scss file, the class still persists the auto parameter.  (I tried this globally and Chrome still hangs on to it as well, tried setting it to 20px, I also know the media query works as I changed the font to purple).

So how would I override the setting?

If you can't override this CSS, then programmatically turning off `pull=right` for the fa-icon just for IE would be a fine solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, removing the pull property for fa-icon and replacing it with `style="float: right"`
did the trick. For example:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="['fas', accordionOpen ? 'chevron-down' : 'chevron-right']" style="float: right"></fa-icon>
```

Appears virtually the same on Chrome as it did before as well.